# JAX-RS change the auto generated json

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have a jax-rs project deployed in Java EE server.
In it a Conference object like so:

```
public final String name;
public List<Person> participants;

... constructors
```

I then keep an arraylist of conferences, and I have this method:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Conference> getList() {
  return conferences;    
}
```

This works as expected.
What I want to do is to change the way json is auto created and instead of returning the array of persons for each conference, I want to return a string which I will later use for lazyloading of the array. How can I do that?

## update

Some more details:
The string will be a link which and ill use in javascript for the lazy loading. My question is how can I change the auto generated json (which include the entire array of participants) to just a string? without creating another object of course. Iv'e tried implementing serializable but it didn't help.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Once the response is sent to the client, any change you make on the object will not be reflected on the client. A `String` is immutable so I'm not sure how you plan to lazy load it with data. Please elaborate on that with a use case.

Comment: The string will be a link which and ill use in javascript for the lazy loading. My question is how can I change the auto generated json (which include the entire array of participants) to just a string? without creating another object of course. Iv'e tried implementing serializable but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is a `MessageBodyWriter<T>` - https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html